# videoview inside viewfliper is overlapping

Tags: android, android-videoview, viewflipper

I have a viewfilper and 2 child layout in it.
Added video view in both child layout.After playing video in first child i moved to the next layout and played the video. I can see the video in first child is over lapping the video in second child.How can we fix this.

Comment: Did you encounter a solution to your problem? Im having the same problem in a Galaxy Note Tab 10.1. Every other devices I have it works fine.

Comment: try to hide the previous videoview when you are moving to the next page. this will be the solution

Comment: Hi tried to do that in and other options but in some devices I continue to encounter the Overlap. I find a solution that work for me, I change from a VideoView to a TextureVideoView (It is a library [link](https://github.com/sprylab/texturevideoview)). But thanks for your quickly reply.